# Retain folder sizes (height/width)

Tags: icons, zooming, ole, powerbuilder

I have an **OleCustomControl** which displays the contents (documents &/or folders) of the path I specify.

I'm able to **zoom in/zoom out (increase/decrease)** which resizes the icons of documents &/or folders. **For ex:** I have set it to Extra Large Icons.

Once I close the application & re- run it, I want to be able to view it in the same way I set it last time i.e. **Extra Large Icons**.

Is there a way by which I can access this setting in power builder code?
If there would be one, I'll maintain the status & then set it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

I can use the **IconSize** property to store the current icon sizes. I store this value & reset it when user opens the application again.

Ex: `oleControl.Object.Document.IconSize`

How I found this?
It should have been simple as the property name says it. However, I found it from the registry settings, where there is a registry entry for IconSize.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't tell us the name of the control, we can't help you with specifics. Check the vendor website for documentation.

If you named the control ole_1, it should be something like this:

ole_1.object.thepropertyname = "thevalue"

or

ole_1.object.themethodname("thevalue")

Comment: Roland, the name of the control is mentioned - OleCustomControl. To this OLE control we insert a control which is Microsoft Web Browser.
The path to be opened is set as below:
THIS.object.Navigate(ls_path)

The icon display type is set by the below statement:
THIS.object.document.currentviewmode = 6
6 indicates Tile View.

Now say I have changed the view type to Extra Large Icons by right clicking, selecting View -> Extra Large Icons. I want to know how I can access this setting so that I can set it back for the user when he comes back to this screen.

Comment: Currently, it sets it to medium icons which is the default for Microsoft Web Browser.

Comment: OleCustomControl is a generic term and does not identify the actual control being used. Since you now mention the Web Browser being the actual control, I have an example you should take a look at: http://www.topwizprogramming.com/freecode_webbrowser.html

Comment: Here is the documentation for the Web Browser control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752043(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I have already checked the first one. I checked the 2nd one i.e. the documentation for the Web browser control but to no avail.